# RecyclerView adds a "empty" layout item and when I click it the app crashes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, crash, kotlin

I didn't add any data to my RecyclerView but it shows a empty box (the one I styled in the layouts for my data) anyways. It crashes with this errormessage

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Here is my customAdapter:

```
class CustomAdapterExercise(var exerciseList: ArrayList<Exercise>, val addList: ArrayList<textAdd>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapterExercise.ViewHolder>() {

val typeAdd = 0
val typeExercise = 1

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    if (position == exerciseList.size + 1) {
        return typeAdd
    }
    else{
        return typeExercise
    }

}

//this method is returning the view for each item in the list
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapterExercise.ViewHolder {

    if (viewType == typeExercise) {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.exercise_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)

    } else {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.add_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

}

//this method is binding the data on the list
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapterExercise.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder.itemViewType == typeAdd) {
        holder.bindAdd(addList[0])
    }
    else{
        if(position != exerciseList.size){
            holder.bindItems(exerciseList[position])
        }
    }
}

//this method is giving the size of the list
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return exerciseList.size + 2
}

//the class is hodling the list view
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bindItems(Exercise: Exercise) { 

        var exerciseAmount = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.exerciseAmount)

        if(exerciseAmount != null){
            exerciseAmount.text = Exercise.exAmount

        }
    }

    fun bindAdd(textAdd: textAdd){
        val addText = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.addText)
        if(addText != null){
            addText.text = textAdd.textAdd
        }

    }
}
}
```

Even if I add some data it still produces a empty box there and I don't get why.
I wonder how can I stop it from producing a empty box always?

Comment: in getItemCount() you are doing "return exerciseList.size + 2", should it be +1? I think that's where an empty item gets added.

Comment: Yeah but if I do +1 it doesnt show my addButton it only shows the "empty" boy again that crashes my app if I click it

Comment: Ah, I see another issue :) in "getItemViewType" -> "position == exerciseList.size + 1". This should be just "position == exerciseList.size". So, let's say you have 5 items.. positions 0-4 will be your exercise items, and then position 5 will be add item.

Comment: You can always add some logs and output the position and type of each item in getItemViewType to ensure these are generated correctly for positions, that usually helps me to debug recycler view issues.

Comment: @sigute it doesn't show the "empty" item anymore but now it crashes when I click on my add button :D

Comment: getting there! :D not sure why that would crash, it might be helpful if you post your logcat.

Comment: @sigute I fixed it nevermind I added a +1 in my main activity too and I removed it and now it works like a charm :) If you want to you can post a answer to it and I will choose yours as the correct one! thank you!!!

Comment: happy to hear it's working :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are issues with calculating the index in RecyclerView:

In getItemCount it should be + 1, instead of + 2, as it only needs to add one additional item for add button.

In getItemViewType position at the end of the list if list length, rather than list lenght +1. This is because position is 0-indexed. So, for example, if you have 5 items, positions 0-4 will be your exercise items, and then position 5 (position == exerciseList.size) will be an add item.

Adding logs in getItemViewType for position and generated view type is helpful for debugging, as it shows which positions are calculated incorrectly very quickly.